# Capture Value From Dropdown Using gtag.js

Tags: google-analytics, gtag.js

Looking to capture the selected input from a dropdown using gtag.js

```js
<a href="#" 
onclick="gtag('event', 'click', {'event_category': 'Distance'});")
class="distance-toggler </a>
<div class="toggler-content" >
<input type="range" min="0" max="4" step="1" value="2" >
<div class="distance-labels" >
<div class="distance-label" id="distance-label-1">.5</div>
<div class="distance-label" id="distance-label-2">1</div>
<div class="distance-label" id="distance-label-3">2</div>
<div class="distance-label" id="distance-label-4">3</div>
<div class="distance-label" id="distance-label-5">5</div>
```

I am currently capturing the click event but I would like to capture the custom value of the dropdown (e.g. 1,2,3,4,5).

On a related note, I am also looking to capture the custom address inputted into a text box

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Address" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you would get the value selected and pass it to GA.

```
<a href="#" 
onclick="gtag('event', 'click', {
    'event_category': 'Distance',
    'event_label': document.getElementById('distance-selector').value,
    'value': document.getElementById('distance-selector').value
});") class="distance-toggler>Test</a>

<input id="distance-selector" type="range" min="0" max="4" step="1" value="2" >
```